# Android : how to call any class from xml file

Tags: android

below is my code which adds tabs in layout.

```
public class MyexplistActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.tryout);

         TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
         tabHost.setup();

         TabSpec browsespec=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
         browsespec.setIndicator("Browse", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_browse_tab));
         browsespec.setContent(R.id.tab1);

         TabSpec advspec=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
         advspec.setIndicator("Advanced Search", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_advsrch_tab));
         advspec.setContent(R.id.tab2);

         TabSpec tgspec=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
         tgspec.setIndicator("Tagged Files", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_tgfiles_tab));
         tgspec.setContent(R.id.tab3);

         tabHost.addTab(browsespec);
         tabHost.addTab(advspec);
         tabHost.addTab(tgspec);

      }
 }
```

tryout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
/>

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="60px"
>

<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="100px" 
android:text="This is tab1"
android:id="@+id/txt1"
/>    

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tab2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="60px"
>

<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="100px" 
android:text="This is tab 2"
android:id="@+id/txt2"
/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tab3"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="60px"
>

<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="100px" 
android:text="This is tab 3"
android:id="@+id/txt3"
/>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Now my question is I want to call another class namely annotate.java when I click on tab1 so that the background coding will be done .So what is the procedure to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can't define in xml what happens when a tab is selected. You have to do that in java, which you are already doing. If Annotate.java is an Activity, then I think you have to subclass TabActivity instead.

It's worth noting also that using TabActivity and TabHost for navigation is no longer standard practice (and in fact TabActivity is deprecated), in favor of using the ActionBar tab navigation with fragments instead. The Android developers site has more information about this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. but I tried below code before this tab view and it works perfectly.But when i use same code for tab view then the tabs are not clickable .#####"TabSpec browsespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Browse");
        browsespec.setIndicator("Browse", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        Intent browseIntent = new Intent(this, Annotate.class);
        browsespec.setContent(browseIntent);"#####